# Pausing a Countdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I basically want the time to stop counting down when someone clicks on the div itself.

So I have the following code

```
var count = 60;

jQuery("#watched_countdown").text(count);

var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
    if(count > 0){
        count = count - 1;
        jQuery("#watched_countdown").text(count);
    }
    else {
       clearInterval(myTimer);
       update_entry_episode(); 
    }
},1000);
```

This code is there for counting down

Then I have this html markup that displays the countdown

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cancel_countdown();">
<div id="watched_countdown"></div>
</a>
```

So basically if someone clicks on the link it should pause the countdown. So I'm thinking that when someone clicks on the link I run another function that possibly pauses the countdown, because I don't want the `update_entry_episode()` function to run when the user clicks on this link.

So visually it should pause the countdown while in the backend it should not run the `update_entry_episode()` which should automatically happen as long as `count` doesn't reach zero.

My main thing is then what should I put in `cancel_countdown()` to stop the `count` variable from decreasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="watched_countdown"></div>

<a href="#cancel" id="cancel">cancel</a>
```

Use **clearInterval**();

```
var count = 60;

$("#watched_countdown").text(count);

var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
    if(count > 0){
        count = count - 1;
        $("#watched_countdown").text(count);
    }
    else {
       clearInterval(myTimer);
       update_entry_episode(); 
    }
},1000);


var cancelCount = function(){
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    myTimer = null;
};

$('body').on('click','#cancel',cancelCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use clearInterval() to 'pause' the timer and then the full setInterval to start it again. I suggest defining the setInterval callback as a named function so you can reference it in multiple places.

Comment: so if I use `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clearInterval()"><div id="watched_countdown"></div></a>`

What will this do exactly, when clicked?

Comment: You need to pass the original setInterval return value to it. I.e. clearInterval(myTimer);

Comment: but will I have access to that variable? 

So doing this 

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)"><div id="watched_countdown"></div></a>`

Will work and do what I need to? It'll pause the timer and all?